# How do I add a key to a row based on its "group"?

Tags: sql, sas, relational-database

I have a data set like this:

```
a 10
a 13
a 14
b 15
b 44
c 64
c 32
d 12
```

I want to write a PROC SQL statement or DATA step that will yield this:

```
a 10 1
a 13 1
a 14 1
b 15 2
b 44 2
c 64 3
c 32 3
d 12 4
```

How do?

```
DATA TEST;
   INPUT id $ value  ;
   DATALINES;
a 10
a 13
a 14
b 15
b 44
c 64
c 32
d 12
;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort your data if needed:

```
proc sort data=test;
by id;
run;
```

Then:

```
data want;
set test;
retain key;
by id;
if _n_ = 1 then key = 0;
if first.id then key = key + 1;
run;
```

The retain statement will retain the value of key through the iterations.
Then, whenever a new id appears, we sum 1 to key.

---

Alternatively as stated by **Keith**, you could use this simplified data step to do the job:

```
data want;
set test;
by id;
if first.id then key + 1;
run;
```

I'll leave both versions here for reference because I think the first one is easier to understand, and the last one from Keith's comments is a lot cleaner.

Comment: You can set the initial value of `key` in the `retain` statement.
`retain key 0` means you don't need the `if _n_=1 then key = 0`

Comment: You could also remove the `retain` statement completely and just put `if first.id then key+1`.  Using `key+1` this way automatically retains the value in the next observation.

Comment: Great suggestions @Keith, should I put some examples on the answer?

Comment: @RamB Probably not necessary, but you could put add a revised version for clarity if you wish.

Comment: You could also (on your first example), initialise the value of `key` to `0` via `retain key 0;` and then eliminate your first `if` statement.  Alternatively you can also eliminate the first `if` statement if you use `key = sum(key, first.id);`.